# An "About" message box for a GUI with Qt

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qt4, messagebox

```
    QMessageBox::about( this, "About Application",
    "<h4>Application is a one-paragraph blurb</h4>\n\n"
"Copyright 1991-2003 Such-and-such. "
"For technical support, call 1234-56789 or see\n"
"<a href=\"http://www.such-and-such.com\">http://www.such-and-such.com</a>" );
```

This code is creating the About message box which I wanted to have with two exceptions:

1)  I would like to change the icon in the message box with an aaa.png file

2)  And I would like to have the link clickable. It looks like hyperlink (it is blue and underlined) but mouse click does not work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a custom `QWidget` for your about widget. By this way, you can put on the widget all you want. By example, you can place `QLabel` using the [`openExternalLinks`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop) property for clickable link.

To display a custom image on the `QWidget`, this [example](http://www.greyc.ensicaen.fr/ensicaen/Docs/Qt4/widgets-imageviewer.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

For the icon, you need to just set the application icon. Something like this:

```
QApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/aaa.png")); // from a resource file
```

As for making the links clickable, I don't think it can be done with the `QMessageBox::about` API directly.

Comment: OK, may be you could tell me, in general, how we can create a widget with hyperlinked text inside?

Answer (score 1):

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText); // this does the magic trick and allows you to click the link
msgBox.setText("Text<br /><a href=\"http://www.such-and-such.com\">http://www.such-and-such.com</a>");
msgBox.setIcon(yourIcon);
msgBox.exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the docs state that the default type for [textFormat is Qt::AutoText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#textFormat-prop). The docs further state that [Qt::AutoText is interpreted as Qt::RichText if Qt::mightBeRichText() returns true, otherwise as Qt::PlainText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#TextFormat-enum). Finally, [mightBeRichText uses a fast and therefore simple heuristic. It mainly checks whether there is something that looks like a tag before the first line break.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#mightBeRichText) So, since you dont have a tag in your first line, it assumes that it is plain text. Set it to RichText explicitely with `msgBox.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);` to make it act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

there's a message in the qtcenter about it:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17365-Clickable-URL-in-QMessageBox

Use http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html#setOpenExternalLinks

Answer (score -1):

**main.cpp**

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/your_icon.png"));
```

**mainwindow.cpp** (into your slot if you have one)

```
void MainWindow::on_aboutAction_triggered()
{
    QMessageBox::about(0, "window title", "<a href='http://www.jeffersonpalheta.com'>jeffersonpalheta.com</a>");
}
```